# DT Editing in Shiny application with client-side processing (server = F) throws JSON Error

Tags: r, json, shiny, shiny-server, dt

I have a Shiny Server application in which the user can edit a datatable, after which some reactive summary statistics update accordingly. I am hosting this app on a fairly slow framework, which is why I want to use client-side processing for the DT rendering, i.e. `server = F` passed to `DT::renderDataTable`. Let me break down the main points of my problem:

- The code is fully operational when `server = T` is passed.
- When passing `server = F`, the browser throws the following error message when the user edits a cell in the DT:

> DataTables warning: table id=DataTables_Table_5 - Invalid JSON
>   response. For more information about this error, please see
>   http://datatables.net/tn/1

An interesting thing is that when this error window is dismissed, **the dependent summary statistics update correctly according to the edit, and the Shiny app carries on**. Hence, everything works except for the error. I should note that I visited the site referred to in the error without becoming any wiser.

Reproducible example below:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

dt = data.frame(V1 = c(1,2), V2 = c(3,4))

server <- function(input, output, session) {

val = reactiveValues(mat = data.table(dt))

output$testDT = renderDataTable({
            DT::datatable(val$mat, editable = TRUE)
}, server = FALSE)

proxy = dataTableProxy('testDT')

observeEvent(input$testDT_cell_edit, {

  info = input$testDT_cell_edit

  str(info)

  i = info$row
  j = info$col
  v = info$val

  if (j == 1){

  val$mat$V1[i] = DT::coerceValue(v, val$mat$V1[i])
  replaceData(proxy, val$mat, rownames = FALSE)

  }

})


}

ui <- fluidPage(
  dataTableOutput('testDT') 
)

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's has been answered on [the Github thread](https://github.com/rstudio/DT/issues/598) and I'm sharing my answer here.

> Probably it's not documented clearly. It has nothing to do with the editing. It's because `replaceData()` calls `reloadData()`, which requires the server-side processing mode. See `?reloadData()`.
>
> > reloadData() only works for tables in the server-side processing mode, e.g. tables rendered with renderDataTable(server = TRUE). The data to be reloaded (i.e. the one you pass to dataTableAjax()) must have exactly the same number of columns as the previous data object in the table.